# How to change background color from fragment using xml file?

Tags: android, xml

I would like to change color of one element in recyclerview on action(for example swipe, but it works fine).

I have used:

```
viewHolder!!.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
```

It works like on screen, because I have different layout like layout_content.

[Gray coolor in wrong place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqY4a.png)

When I add line like below color doesn't change at all. Please notice, that I had to implement another binding with other layout which uses another .xml file to get some preferences.

```
layoutBinding.vContent.frameLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY)
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_list_item_incoming_leads"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_2"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_8">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_32"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_32"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_16"
            android:contentDescription="@string/notification_list_close_button_content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_grey_primary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLeadFullName"
            style="@style/Regular.13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvSimpleText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvInformation"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            tools:text="%leadfullname" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProductNotification"
            style="@style/Regular.13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvSimpleText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvInformation"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            tools:text="%product" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSimpleText"
            style="@style/Regular.13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvProductNotification"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvLeadFullName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvInformation"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            tools:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvInformation"
            style="@style/Regular.15"
            android:layout_width="211dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            tools:text="You received a new Lead" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvData"
            style="@style/Regular.13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnClose"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="11 Oct 2021" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            style="@style/Regular.13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnClose"
            tools:text="hh:ss" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white">
    </solid>
    <corners
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/spacing_8"
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/spacing_8"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/spacing_8"
        android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/spacing_8">
    </corners>
</shape>
```

How to have access to `.xml` file and change background from fragment directly to `bg_list_item_incoming_leads.xml` maybe that would be a solution?

EDIT, additional information:

BaseFragment

```
abstract class BaseFragmentBindings<VB : ViewBinding, LB : ViewBinding, VM : BaseViewModel>(private val inflate: Inflate<VB>, private val secondInflate: Inflate<LB>) :
    Fragment() {

    private var binding: VB? = null
    protected val layout: VB
        get() = binding!!

    private var bindingLayout: LB? = null
    protected val layoutBinding: LB
        get() = bindingLayout!!

    abstract val vm: VM

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = inflate.invoke(inflater, container, false)
        bindingLayout = secondInflate.invoke(inflater, container, false)
        return binding!!.root
    }
```

fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class NotificationListFragment :
    BaseFragmentBindings<FragmentNotificationListBinding, LayoutListItemNotificationBinding, NotificationListViewModel>
        (FragmentNotificationListBinding::inflate, LayoutListItemNotificationBinding::inflate) {
    override val vm: NotificationListViewModel by viewModels()

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below snippet, get reference to background, which is `Drawable`, check if its `ColorDrawable` (in your case it is set only in XML then it will always be) and if is then use class casting and set new color, other params should stay unchanged (like rounded corners set with `<corners` tag, btw. `app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_8"` in main XML set for `FrameLayout` is no-op, it was left there probably when this item was a `CardView`)

```
Drawable background = layoutBinding.vContent.frameLayout.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
    ((ColorDrawable) background).setColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Comment: I made edit for you for more information, I have implemented your code but it doesn't work, color is not changed. If I understand well if I change color of frameLayout it should work I even force to be ColorDrawable. val background = layoutBinding.vContent.frameLayout.background as ColorDrawable.

Comment: I think issue is somewhere else with implementation of binding maybe? I tried to setText of element and it doesn't work as well

Comment: or... it has to be changed with declaration of id from adapter i.e. what would be your suggestions?
Thank you for your answer.